# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables while SSH'd into instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Node app on EB. I've set the "Environment Properties" in the Web Console and everything works wonderfully.

However, I need to SSH into my instance and run a couple of diagnostic scripts. Those environment variables don't seem to be loaded except through the command that starts `npm run`.

Where are they hiding?

Answer (score 1):

I use the Ruby version of EB, but on my system at least the environment variables are stored in `/etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh`, which is a symlink to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars`.